# Pandas Dataframe: Replacing NaN with row average

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I am  trying to learn pandas but I have been puzzled with the following. I want to replace NaNs in a DataFrame with the row average. Hence something like `df.fillna(df.mean(axis=1))` should work but for some reason it fails for me. Am I missing anything, is there something wrong with what I'm doing? Is it because its not implemented? see [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478641/how-to-replace-nan-with-sum-of-the-row-in-pandas-datatframe)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
​
pd.__version__
Out[44]:
'0.15.2'

In [45]:
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['c1'] = [1, 2, 3]
df['c2'] = [4, 5, 6]
df['c3'] = [7, np.nan, 9]
df

Out[45]:
    c1  c2  c3
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   NaN
2   3   6   9

In [46]:  
df.fillna(df.mean(axis=1)) 

Out[46]:
    c1  c2  c3
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   NaN
2   3   6   9
```

However something like this looks to work fine

```
df.fillna(df.mean(axis=0)) 

Out[47]:
    c1  c2  c3
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
```

Comment: That functionality is still not implemented - the [issue remains open](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4514).

Comment: As for oct 2022 the functionality is already working, now you can specify axis=1 in fillna

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As commented the axis argument to fillna is [NotImplemented](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4514).

```
df.fillna(df.mean(axis=1), axis=1)
```

*Note: this would be critical here as you don't want to fill in your nth columns with the nth row average.*

For now you'll need to iterate through:

```
m = df.mean(axis=1)
for i, col in enumerate(df):
    # using i allows for duplicate columns
    # inplace *may* not always work here, so IMO the next line is preferred
    # df.iloc[:, i].fillna(m, inplace=True)
    df.iloc[:, i] = df.iloc[:, i].fillna(m)

print(df)

   c1  c2   c3
0   1   4  7.0
1   2   5  3.5
2   3   6  9.0
```

An alternative is to fillna the transpose and then transpose, which may be more efficient...

```
df.T.fillna(df.mean(axis=1)).T
```

Answer (score 26):

As an alternative, you could also use an `apply` with a `lambda` expression like this:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.fillna(row.mean()), axis=1)
```

yielding also

```
    c1   c2   c3
0  1.0  4.0  7.0
1  2.0  5.0  3.5
2  3.0  6.0  9.0
```

Answer (score 6):

### For an efficient solution, use `DataFrame.where`:

We could use `where` on `axis=0`:

```
df.where(df.notna(), df.mean(axis=1), axis=0)
```

or `mask` on `axis=0`:

```
df.mask(df.isna(), df.mean(axis=1), axis=0)
```

By using `axis=0`, we can fill in the missing values in each column with the row averages.

These methods perform very similarly (`where` does slightly better on large DataFrames (300_000, 20)) and is ~35-50% faster than the numpy methods posted here and is 110x faster than the double transpose method.

*Some benchmarks:*

```
df = creator()

>>> %timeit df.where(df.notna(), df.mean(axis=1), axis=0)
542 ms ± 3.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %timeit df.mask(df.isna(), df.mean(axis=1), axis=0)
555 ms ± 21.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %timeit df.fillna(0) + df.isna().values * df.mean(axis=1).values.reshape(-1,1)
751 ms ± 22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %timeit fill = pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(df.mean(1).to_numpy()[:, None], df.shape), columns=df.columns, index=df.index); df.update(fill, overwrite=False)
848 ms ± 22.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %timeit df.apply(lambda row: row.fillna(row.mean()), axis=1)
1min 4s ± 5.32 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> %timeit df.T.fillna(df.mean(axis=1)).T
1min 5s ± 2.4 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

def creator():
    A = np.random.rand(300_000, 20)
    A.ravel()[np.random.choice(A.size, 300_000, replace=False)] = np.nan
    return pd.DataFrame(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll propose an alternative that involves casting into numpy arrays. Performance wise, I think this is more efficient and probably scales better than the other proposed solutions so far.

The idea being to use an indicator matrix (`df.isna().values` which is 1 if the element is N/A, 0 otherwise) and broadcast-multiplying that to the row averages.
Thus, we end up with a matrix (exactly the same shape as the original df), which contains the row-average value if the original element was N/A, and 0 otherwise.

We add this matrix to the original df, making sure to fillna with 0 so that, in effect, we have filled the N/A's with the respective row averages.

```py
# setup code
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['c1'] = [1, 2, 3]
df['c2'] = [4, 5, 6]
df['c3'] = [7, np.nan, 9]

# fillna row-wise
row_avgs = df.mean(axis=1).values.reshape(-1,1)
df = df.fillna(0) + df.isna().values * row_avgs
df
```

giving

```
    c1   c2   c3
0   1.0  4.0  7.0
1   2.0  5.0  3.5
2   3.0  6.0  9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can broadcast the mean to a DataFrame with the same index as the original and then use `update` with `overwrite=False` to get the behavior of `.fillna`. Unlike `.fillna`, `update` allows for filling when the Indices have duplicated labels. Should be faster than the looping .fillna for smaller than 50,000 rows or so.

```
fill = pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(df.mean(1).to_numpy()[:, None], df.shape), 
                    columns=df.columns,
                    index=df.index)

df.update(fill, overwrite=False)
print(df)

     1    1    1
0  1.0  4.0  7.0
0  2.0  5.0  3.5
0  3.0  6.0  9.0
```