# Custom Selection of dataframe and replacing values of certain rows with mean

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

So basically I have a dataset somewhat like this
[image: dataset iamge]

I want to select only 'Havard' rows and get their mean and replace it with missing values in GPA only for 'Havard' and different mean value for Stanford

I tried `data['GPA'].fillna(data['GPA'].mean())` but it would just fill it with mean value of the whole column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fillna by groupby outputs in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41680089/how-to-fillna-by-groupby-outputs-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a file (`yourdata.csv`) containing the data outlined in your question, you could use the below example to replace all null values in the `GPA` column with the mean `GPA` of the corresponding `University` for each row.

This solution makes use of `df.apply` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)) to apply the same conditional logic to each row within the `df`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('yourdata.csv')

df['GPA'].fillna(np.nan, inplace=True) # Ensuring null values in GPA col are np.nan

df['GPA'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: df[df['University'] == row['University']]['GPA'].mean() 
    if np.isnan(row['GPA']) else row['GPA'], axis=1
)
```

If you **only** want to perform this logic on rows where `University == 'Harvard'` (i.e. not fill null GPA values in Stanford, Oxford etc. rows with their respective mean) you could simply add this as a further condition within the `lambda` applied to each row to ensure that only rows where `University == 'Harvard'` are affected.

```py
# Same imports, original df and fillna as above snippet
df['GPA'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: df[df['University'] == row['University']]['GPA'].mean() 
    if np.isnan(row['GPA']) and row['University'] == 'Harvard' 
    else row['gpa'], axis=1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
df['GPA']=df[df['University']=='Havard'].fillna(df.mean())
```