# Delete and replace Nan values with mean of the rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very big DataFrame that looks like:

```
    c1   c2    c3
0  NaN  1.0   NaN
1  NaN  NaN   NaN
2  3.0  6.0   9.0
3  NaN  7.0  10.0
...
```

I want to:

1- Delete the rows with all "Nan" values. like the second row in the sample.

2- Replace all the "Nan" values in other rows with the mean of the rows.

Note: in the rows, we have different "Nan" values.
could you please help me with that? Thanks.

Also, this link does not solve my question:
[Pandas Dataframe: Replacing NaN with row average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058590/pandas-dataframe-replacing-nan-with-row-average)

Here is a sample of my DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame()
df['c1'] = [np.nan, np.nan, 3, np.nan]
df['c2'] = [1, np.nan, 6, 7]
df['c3'] = [np.nan, np.nan, 9, 10]
```

Update:
When we don't want to consider the mean of all rows.
sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
df['c1'] = [np.nan, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 5]
df['c2'] = [1, np.nan, 3, 11, 5]
df['c3'] = [1, np.nan, 3, 11, np.nan]
df['c4'] = [3, np.nan, 3, 11, 5]

output: 
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = [1,  3, 4, 5]
df['c1'] = [ 5/3, 3, 11, 5]
df['c2'] = [1,  3, 11, 5]
df['c3'] = [1,  3, 11, 5]
df['c4'] = [3,  3, 11, 5]
df
```

For this part, I don't want to consider the value of id for calculating the mean of row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a dictionary from the column names and row means and pass it to `fillna` to fill the NaN values. Then drop the NaN rows (which won't get filled in because all NaN rows have mean NaN).

```
out = df.fillna(dict.fromkeys(df.columns, df.mean(axis=1))).dropna()
```

Another possibility is to transpose the DataFrame and use `fillna` to fill, then transpose back:

```
df_T = df.T
df_T.fillna(df_T.mean()).T.dropna()
```

Output:

```
    c1   c2    c3
0  1.0  1.0   1.0
2  3.0  6.0   9.0
3  8.5  7.0  10.0
```

Comment: Thank you @enke. It works for me. A quick question, since my data is very very large, is this method fast enough? Sorry, I am new to python and data frame and probably this is very basic question.

Comment: @Yellowman should be fast enough, I think

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

how about this :

```
df = df.T.fillna(df.mean(axis=1)).T.dropna()
print(df)
```

output:

```
>>>
    c1   c2    c3
0  1.0  1.0   1.0
2  3.0  6.0   9.0
3  8.5  7.0  10.0
```

Comment: Thanks @eshirvana. However, this provide the mean of coulmns, not the rows.

Comment: @Yellowman you already got your answer , but see my updated answer as well

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes. It works now.

Comment: Can I ask a quick question? I want to replace the df.mean which return the mean of row. I mean, I want to replace the Nan with mean of column 1 until the end. Do you know how to solve that? I asked this question in the first version very bad.

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly , provide sample data and desired output

Comment: I have added an update to the main question.